# How can I test HTTPS endpoints in go?

Tags: ssl, testing, go

So I'm trying to mock out a response to an https request using `httptest.TLSServer` but the `http.Client` making the request keeps telling me that the server is giving an invalid http response. I bet this is because there's no actual SSL cert. Is there any way I can get the client to ignore tls while still mocking out an https request?

The test code in question

```
func TestFacebookLogin(t *testing.T) {
    db := glob.db
    server := httptest.NewTLSServer(http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        resp := `
        {
          "id": "123",
          "email": "blah",
          "first_name": "Ben",
          "last_name": "Botwin"
        }
        `

        w.Write([]byte(resp))
    }))
    defer server.Close()

    transport := &http.Transport{
        Proxy: func(r *http.Request) (*url.URL, error) {
            return url.Parse(server.URL)
        },
    }

    svc := userService{db: db, client: &http.Client{Transport: transport}}

    _, err := svc.FacebookLogin("asdf")

    if err != nil {
        t.Errorf("Error found: %s", err)
    }

}
```

And the request that I'm trying to make:

```
url := "https://<Some facebook api endpoint>"
req, err := http.NewRequest("GET", url, nil)
resp, err := client.Do(req)
if err != nil {
    return nil, err
}
defer resp.Body.Close()
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mocking HTTPS responses in Go](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27880930/mocking-https-responses-in-go)

Answer (score 6):

The test server uses a self signed certificate. There are two ways to avoid errors.  The first is to use an HTTP client configured with the [test server's certificates](https://godoc.org/net/http/httptest#Server.TLS):

```
certs := x509.NewCertPool()
for _, c := range server.TLS.Certificates {
    roots, err := x509.ParseCertificates(c.Certificate[len(c.Certificate)-1])
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("error parsing server's root cert: %v", err)
    }
    for _, root := range roots {
        certs.AddCert(root)
    }
}
client := http.Client{
    Transport: &http.Transport{
        TLSClientConfig: &tls.Config{
            RootCAs: certs,
        },
    },
}
```

[playground example](http://play.golang.org/p/dKSOZE2ePY)

An easier option is to skip cert verification:

```
client := http.Client{
    Transport: &http.Transport{
        TLSClientConfig: &tls.Config{
            InsecureSkipVerify: true,
        },
    },
}
```

[playground example](http://play.golang.org/p/6kZ1mxFmUM)

There's an additional issue. The client expects to connect to a proxy server, but the it's actually connecting to the test server directly.  Try hooking the dial function instead of the proxy:

```
client := http.Client{
    Transport: &http.Transport{
        Dial: func(network, addr string) (net.Conn, error) {
            return net.Dial("tcp", server.URL[strings.LastIndex(server.URL, "/")+1:])
        },
        TLSClientConfig: &tls.Config{
            InsecureSkipVerify: true,
        },
    },
}
```

[playground example](http://play.golang.org/p/Rj560Av13D)

Comment: Now I'm getting a weird Malformed Response error. Any idea why?

Comment: @thecodethinker I need more information to determine what the error might be.   I provided two working programs that test an https.  Start with one of those.

Comment: When I try testing with the `InsecureSkipVerify` I get this error `malformed HTTP response "\x15\x03\x01\x00\x02\x02\x16"`.

Do you know what that is?

Comment: Oh, this is yet another issue  The test server is responding with the TLS handshake, but the client is expecting the HTTP response from a proxy.   See updated answer for fix.

Comment: Why do you only want things after a `/` character for the `Dial` call?

Comment: The Dial call is now giving me a `400 bad request` without even hitting the server. Why would this happen? Also I'm sorry for all the mini questions

Comment: Dial takes a host:port.  The test server url is documented to be http://host:proto.  Therefore, we take everything after the "/".  It's  unlikely that net.Dial is returning an error with "400 bad request".

Comment: It's sending back a body of "400 Bad Request." I'm not sure if Dial is returning that, but the actual Handler for the test server is never being called

Comment: I added [this working example](http://play.golang.org/p/Rj560Av13D) to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to use the http client provided by the test server:

```
httpClient := server.Client()
```